Different order for multiple citations and references
I would like to get a different order for multiple citations (ynt: ordered by date) and references (nyt: ordered by author). I am using two references contexts in the following document:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@book{Alpha2000,
    Author = {Alpha, A.},
    Publisher = {One Publisher},
    Title = {Alpha Life},
    Year = {2000}}
@book{Beta1970,
    Author = {Beta, B.},
    Publisher = {Another Publisher},
    Title = {Beat Life},
    Year = {1970}}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[sorting=nyt,style=authoryear,sortcites=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\newrefcontext[sorting=ynt]

\parencite{Alpha2000,Beta1970}

\parencite{Beta1970,Alpha2000}

% \printbibliography[type=none] % <-- ???

\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]
\printbibliography

\end{document}




The calls to \parencite (with multiple citations) generate nothing and I have no error message!
(as biblatex should issue a warning or error, I reported this issue).
Note: Simple citations work perfectly.
Question
If I uncomment the line \printbibliography[type=none], I get the expected result (but the method seems a bit surprising to me).



Is there a correct way to achieve the desired result?

@cfr You are right: the a complicates my example unnecessarily. I edited my question: I request the orders ynt and nyt.

thanks for editing.

biblatex only requests that Biber generate data for a given refcontext if that refcontext is used in a \printbibliography or similar. That's why things work with \printbibliography[type=none]: Even though the command does not print anything due to the type filter it still gets Biber to generate the relevant data.
If you don't have a matching bibliography call for one of the refcontexts you want to use, you can manually ask for data generation with \GenRefcontextData{<refcontext options>}.
The following will work as expected.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,sortcites=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Alpha2000,
  author    = {Alpha, A.},
  publisher = {One Publisher},
  title     = {Alpha Life},
  year      = {2000},
}
@book{Beta1970,
  author    = {Beta, B.},
  publisher = {Another Publisher},
  title     = {Beat Life},
  year      = {1970},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\newrefcontext[sorting=ynt]
\GenRefcontextData{sorting=ynt}

\parencite{Alpha2000,Beta1970}

\parencite{Beta1970,Alpha2000}

\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]
\printbibliography
\end{document}



Extract from documentation of \GenRefcontextData: [...] e.g. to sort citations with the sortcites option when the sorting of citations requires a different refcontext to that used for the actual reference list. Thanks !
